# Python not find email adress srt

Tags: javascript, python, string

import urllib, urllib2, cookielib
    import re
    from requests import session

```
nr=85365
username = 'nucred'
password = 'steaua123'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
nr=85365
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'password' : password})
nrs = urllib.urlencode({'nr' : nr})
opener.open('http://sssssd/takelogin.php', login_data)
resp = opener.open('http://ssssssd/userdetails.php?id=', str(nr))
s=resp.read()
ss=re.findall(r"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}",s)
print ss
nr+=1
```

output:

[]

> > > 

i change this:

```
resp = opener.open('http://ssssssd/userdetails.php?id=85365')
```

output:

[test@gmail.com]

> > > 

I want while True: nr+=1

Comment: Can you fix the formatting from your question? (I assume it needs fixing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the OpenerDirector.open() method wrong. Specifically you are passing the data parameter wrong.

Try this instead. This one does not use the data parameter.

```
resp = opener.open('http://ssssssd/userdetails.php?id=' + str(nr))
```

You need not pass the data parameter in this case but if  you choose to pass it, you can try the following

```
from urllib import urlencode
params = {'id': nr}
resp = opener.open('http://ssssssd/userdetails.php', data=urlencode(params))
```

Comment: sys.stdout=open("email.txt","w")
    print ss
    sys.stdout.close()

Comment: I would suggest going through this document - https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html. This has examples to for file operations